# Percent correct metric for mental rotation task?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

There is a classic study:

Shepard RN, Metzler J. Mental rotation of three-dimensional objects. Science. 1971;171: 701–703.

which showed that when people are asked to tell whether two 3D objects are "rotated" versions of each other (as opposed to different objects), the average time to generate a correct response is linearly related to the angle of rotation.

My question is: has anyone ever held the response window constant, and measured % correct?